# andengine onresume() change background color

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm writing a live wallpaper with andengine which can change background color every time the device is being woken up.

I tried to test with the onresume function, but it gives me an error when it does  something with the mScene. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(0f, 0.419639f, 0.6235308f));


}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: have you tried using onResumeGame instead so that you get when andengine has resumed, rather than the wallpaper?

Comment: Hi, onResumeGame works, thank you. But when the device is resumed, I can see the noticeable change of the color. How can i make the transformation unnoticeable by naked eyes?